# Java using PHP shell_exec returns nothing

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

With some trouble and some help I managed it to install Java on my Ubuntu server. It's located in `usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45`
On the commandline I can now see my java version `javac -version` and compile java programs.

However when I am trying to do the same thing in PHP `shell_exec`, nothing but a white page appears. Also compiling java files would not work.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('javac -version');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Does it have to do something with the paths? If so, how can I set that path to the location where my java jars are located? There is not that much to find on Google about PHP + java by shell_exec

Answer (score 0):

You should first figure out the full path to javac. Run this from the command line:

which javac

Then update your shell_exec command to include the full path:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/path/to/javac -version');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```